# Xrandr issue with dual screen

Tags: linux-mint, xrandr, mate-desktop

I have an issue with xrandr and my dual screen setup. This happend suddenly after a reboot, so there are no (intentionally) changed settings. Here is what happened:

My external monitor stands left to my laptop, but suddenly my system behaves as the monitor is on the right side. I went into the monitor prefs dialog of the Mate desktop and moved the screen accordingly. I noted the miniature created a trace as i dragged it. After I applied the change, the displays switched as expected, but I cannot click on the display it **triggers clicks on the other screen.** So the dialog "Keep changes ..." is on the internal monitor but I have to click the corresponding location on the external screen. The visible pointer is on the external screen, but an "invisible" pointer is on the internal screen raising the click events.

This is the output of `xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  50.03  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     59.95  
   1280x960      59.99  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       59.97  
   640x400       59.96  
   640x350       59.84  
VGA-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I never had to debug issues with graphics so please ask for more information if required.